# VNC - How to share only certain part of screen?

Tags: vnc, screen-sharing

Is there a VNC Server able to share only a certain region of the screen and not the whole one / single application?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to share specific screen coordinates, I'm pretty sure UltraVnc can share the window for a specific application...

Comment: When answering a question, ensure that your answer is detailed enough for the asker to implement it, or apply it to his situation. (How do you share a specific window in UltraVNC?)